# Pass variable with onclick method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a button dynamically and I want when my button click and onclick event fired, a variable pass with this event.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
//btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click(32)); <-- I want something like this
divUserUploadedList.Controls.Add(btn);
```

And this is Onclick event:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I want to access that value here
}
```

Comment: where does the value come from? Does it come from user input, or is it constant value - does the value ever change?

Comment: You can subscribe to an event, you cannot pass arguments. Why 32?

Comment: @user1666620 This value is id of a row from a table and yes its change

Comment: @TimSchmelter 32 is just example, Its id of some rows from a table. These buttons already have an event and they can successfully fire that event

Comment: you can do this through button's **CommanArgument** property.

Comment: @HosseinR: but you only know which row of the table was clicked _after_ the button was clicked. You should use the `Button`'s `CommandArgument` as Mirza already has mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using **CommandArgument** property

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Click += btn_Click;
            btn.CommandArgument = "12"; //<-- you can pass argument like this
            divUserUploadedList.Controls.Add(btn);

        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            string value = btn.CommandArgument;
        }
```

Comment: Yes tnx, That's what I need

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is probably the CommandArgument property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx